# Arcpy ListFields field types different from Layer Properties

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, fields-attributes

I'm trying to add some functionality to an ArcPy toolbox to check the column names and types of an input feature class.

It seems that the types that Python uses are different from the types in ArcMap itself?

For example, a column of type `float` in the layer properties menu in python is type `Single`

for the other column types:

```py
Text: String,
Long:Integer,
Short:SmallInteger
```

I haven't found a reference for the full universe of options [only this documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/arcgis-field-data-types.htm) and there's no mention of this distinction in [the docs for ListFields](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfields.htm), it just uses the Python types, with no mention of the difference between Python and ArcMap.

is there a better way to be working with field types than by name like this? Is there documentation on this that I haven't found?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, but what about arcpy.Describe() ?
Desrcibe:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe.htm
Table:https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-functions/table-properties.htm
Fields, check (type parameter)
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm

Comment: This has been an issue forever, it's a pain - https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/different-names-for-types-with-arcpy-fieldlist/td-p/430965

Comment: @user2856, thanks very much for that link. I posted this fully expecting to have missed an obvious way that this should be handled. Can't say I'm enthusiastic about being less stupid than I thought I was. This is a pretty significant "bug" if it can be called that.

Comment: AddField will accept those keywords if you use them, there's a note on the Field object topic: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/field.htm

Answer (score 3):

[Add Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm) has a list too. I don't think there is a page mapping parameter types. As you are developing an arcpy toolbox, stick to the naming conventions used in the geoprocessing tools as they only accept those. You just have to assume that your users are savvy enough to realise "Text" is "string" and vice versa.

If you want to help your users then I suggest editing the [item description](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-documenting-tools-and-toolboxes.htm) of the tool you are developing and provide help along with each parameter.

Comment: yeah actually, that's part of what I'm struggling with as the list in `AddField` uses the arcmap data types, not the data types from `ListFields`. I think if I was a user of the tool, I would expect text vs. string to be a meaningful distinction of some sort because why else would there be a difference. I might just make a dict to handle the difference in the warning message strings.